# Issue with Richfaces Datatable filter search

Tags: spring, jsf, richfaces

Here is the scenario i have a Richfaces datatable where i have added filter concept like below

```
<rich:column width="250px" sortBy="#{test.name}" filterExpression="#{fn:equalsIgnoreCase(test.name, filterValue)}"
                    filterValue="#{InventoryFilter.name}">
```

and all bean initialized by application-context.xml and scope of the bean `request`

EDIT:-

```
 <bean id="InventoryFilter" class="com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.filter.InventoryFilter" scope="request" />
```

Now when i am switching tab ,let us suppose from **Tab A** to **Tab B** old search value still coming while each tab i have defined `switchType="server"`

So it mean when i am swtiching  tabs a request is going to server so my application should initialized **InventoryFilter.java** class.

But it not working please someone guide me what i am doing wrong?

**EDIT:- Tab Code**

```
<rich:tabPanel id="tabPanel1" switchType="server"
                        selectedTab="#{panelMenuBean.selectedTabName}"
                        value="#{panelMenuBean.selectedTabName}"
                        style="max-width:500px; height:300px;"
                        itemChangeListener="#{inventoriesBean.getClearBean}">


                        <rich:tab id="customerTab"
                            name="#{bsmPortalLabel['tab.inventory.customer']}" rendered="#{loginBean.isInventoriesCustomerTabEnable()}">
</rich:tab>

//SOME Other tabs here

</rich:tabPanel>
```

Comment: You should show all the relevant code, fi the behavior is caused by tabs then shows the tabs.

Comment: added tab code above

Comment: So the table is not in the tab?

Comment: No this table outside the tab ..Ok i got your point now this table not inside the tab ..it will not create instance of Filter class ? Any how what i have to do resolve the issue?

Comment: I'd assume the bean is created when it's needed. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. You set a filter value for the table and you want to reset it, or what?